# Multiple appendices prefix names

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

For my dissertation, I have a LaTeX template, which alters the prefix of the appendix titles, such that instead of 'A [app name]' I get 'Paper A [app name]'. Great! Except that I would like to have a normal appendix afterwards, i.e. with 'Appendix A [app name]', 'Appendix B [app name]' etc. Can I have two prefix for my appendices? Or switch prefix in my master document somehow?

Preamble.tex:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
...
% Change some default names
\addto\captionsenglish{ 
  \renewcommand\appendixname{Paper} % change Appendix to Paper
...
}
```

Master.tex:

```
...
\part{Papers}\label{part:papers}
\includepaper{papers/paperA/paperA}
\includepaper{papers/paperB/paperB}

\part{Appendix}\label{part:appendix}
\include{Appendix/appendix}
...
```

(I would like this to be the case in the table of contents as well)

Comment: Try putting `\addto\captionsenglish{ 
  \renewcommand\appendixname{Paper}}` just before `\part{Appendix}\label{part:appendix}`.

Comment: Hi @Harish, thank for the comment! Unfortunately that didn't work (I am assuming you meant `\appendixname{Appendix}`)

Comment: Is this question still important?

Comment: Hi @ChristianHupfer. Yes, I still haven't solved this problem and am handing in my thesis later this year! Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: @ChrisV: I'll try to look tomorrow. It's late here already

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: That would be amazing!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Hi Christian, have you had any luck with this challenge yet?

Comment: @ChrisV: No, not yet. I struggle with `titlesec`. Do you have some compilable document version, to work with?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I am using [this template](http://sqrt-1.dk/latex/latex.php#phdtemplate). In Master.tex I have these lines:
    `\part{Papers}\label{part:papers}  
    ...  
    \includepaper{papers/paperA/paperA}  
    \includepaper{papers/paperB/paperB}  
    ...  
    \part{Appendix}\label{part:appendix}  
    \include{Appendix/appendix}`

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, the help section took me a while (too long) to figure out...

Comment: I have found a solution for this problem. The solution was quite specific too my template, I suspect, but it include the use of this line: `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix title}`

Comment: Can you post this as an answer, maybe with an explanation? Right now, your comment seems to answer a different question.

Comment: Hi @Johannes_B Thanks for commenting. I actually didn't know how to post an answer, but I have tried it now. Let me know if it makes more sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was simply to insert a chapter using `\chapter*{}` to remove numbering, i.e. the prefix, and then add the `\addcontentsline` prior to the chapter as shown below. This way, I manually have to added any wished prefix to the (second) appendix, so it is not a full solution, but a useful hack.

```
...
\part{Papers}\label{part:papers}
\includepaper{papers/paperA/paperA}
\includepaper{papers/paperB/paperB}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix title}

\part{Appendix}\label{part:appendix}
\include{Appendix/appendix}
...
```

Comment: A `\cleardoublepage` right before the `addcontentsline` would be helpful to ensure that the right page number is used.